# Securing our SQL server database when using Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sql-server, architecture

I  have been building power apps with SharePoint. and i always secure the datasource. so for example if we have this case:-

1. User submit a request
2. the manager review the submitted request and can Approve/Reject

now in SharePoint i create 2 lists:-

Request List, with these fields:-

1. ID
2. Title
3. Description
4. Approval username

Approval List

1. Request ID
2. Approve/Reject
3. comment

and when a user submit a request >> the will create 2 items one inside the Request list and one inside the Approval list >> set the request item to be read-only using list item permission using Power automate>> set the approval item to only be editable by the approval username using Power automate and so on..

now i want to build my first power app which uses SQL server instead of SharePoint >> then how i need to structure the sql tables? and can is set permission on the sql server table level? so if  a user access the sql server then they can not view or edit rows they are not allowed to view/edit, similar to how i secure the SharePoint list items? and advice? i know there are 2 options for sql connectors Implicit and explicit

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered Dataverse instead of SQL? It might be easier.

Comment: @CallumCrowley Thanks for the reply. I do not have any knowledge in Dataverse, my experience is in SharePoint and SQL Server + Power apps

Comment: It might be worth learning about Dataverse, it's very powerful.

Comment: @CallumCrowley yes i agree with you, but due to time limitation i cannot use Dataverse for this project.

Comment: It sounds like your question is off topic, might be better posted on a SQL server forum. This forum is for SharePoint specific questions.